# mci communications services inc. d/b/a verizon business

Tags: google-analytics

Since September 2018 our Google Analytics reports for the dozen or so websites we host have recorded a substantial increase in sessions from the following service provider: "mci communications services inc. d/b/a verizon business". I don't think these are actual visits from real people, but I can't figure out how to investigate if this is spam or something else.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I've reached out to Google support, but their response is that the sessions are real and there's nothing else they can do.

I've also discussed with our IT staff, thinking the sessions may be a result of our web monitoring software. But the IT staff turned off the monitoring software and the sessions via mci are still being recorded.

Before Sept. 2018, for our most popular site we had maybe 20 or so sessions via mci per week.  Starting in Sept we started receiving about 2,000 per week.  And it's been consistently that high since then.  These represent about 75% of our website sessions. According to the City ID in Google Analytics, the sessions are originating in New York City. But the analytics data doesn't tell me much beyond that (as far as I can tell).

Thoughts/suggestions on how to figure out what these sessions represent?

Answer (score 0):

We stopped using Analytics because of privacy issues,  but when used Orion was not recording their pings as 'mci communications services inc. d/b/a verizon business,' so must be some other entity.

-Stephen Klein
CUNY Graduate Center